# Change text on hover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button to select images, it's default state is "Select Image", after an image is selected, the innerHTML of the button is changed to the filename.
Now, what I want to do, is that if I hover over the button while it does not say "Select Image", I want it to say "Select a different image", and then onmouseout I want it to go back to what it was before (the image filename).

I put together the following, but it's not working... I am open to JS and jQuery options.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    var btn = document.getElementById('file-button');
    if (btn.innerHTML !== "Select Image") {
        var temp = btn.innerHTML;
        btn.onmouseover = btn.innerHTML = "Select a different image";
        btn.onmouseout = btn.innerHTML = temp;
    }
});
```

**SOLUTION** -- thanks to Ian

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    var btn = document.getElementById('file-button');
    btn.onmouseover = function () {
        if (this.innerHTML !== "Select Image") {
            var temp = this.innerHTML;
            this.innerHTML = "Select a different image";
        }
    };

    btn.onmouseout = function () {
        if (this.innerHTML !== "Select Image") {
            this.innerHTML = temp;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    var btn = document.getElementById('file-button');
    if (btn.innerHTML !== "Select Image") {
        var temp = btn.innerHTML;
        btn.onmouseover = function () {
            this.innerHTML = "Select a different image";
        };

        btn.onmouseout = function () {
            this.innerHTML = temp;
        };
    }
});
```

You need to set the `.onmouseover` and `.onmouseout` properties as functions. Then, you might as well reference the button with `this`, instead of `btn`.

**UPDATE:**

I think you want to rearrange your logic to something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    var btn = document.getElementById('file-button');
    var temp = btn.innerHTML;
    btn.onmouseover = function () {
        if (this.innerHTML !== "Select Image") {
            temp = this.innerHTML;
            this.innerHTML = "Select a different image";
        }
    };

    btn.onmouseout = function () {
        if (this.innerHTML !== "Select Image") {
            this.innerHTML = temp;
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3WkXp/

Comment: I tried this in a codepen and it works, but when I apply it to mine it doesn't :/ and no errors appear in the console. Hmm

Comment: @user1994446 I think you need to rethink your original logic. This will correctly bind the events and do what I think you're looking for. But I'm not sure your `if` statement is correct. Basically, your code is saying "On load, if the button's innerHTML is NOT "Select Image", ONLY THEN bind these events. So are you sure that your button's innerHTML is NOT "Select Image"? Can you please provide your HTML for this? What exactly is the "button"? `<button>`? `<input type="button" />`?

Comment: I have `<div id="file-button" class="selectimages">Select Image</div>`
when the image is selected it shows me the filename and size, example "myimage.png" (80 KB). When I mouseover the button/div it doesn't change, and no errors are in the console.

Comment: I changed the script for debugging:
`window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    var btn = document.getElementById('file-button');
    if (btn.innerHTML !== "Select Image") {
        var temp = this.innerHTML;
        btn.onmouseover = function () {
            alert(this.innerHTML); // NOTE THIS LINE
            this.innerHTML = "Select a different image";
        };

        btn.onmouseout = function () {
            this.innerHTML = temp;
        };
    }
});
`
I don't get an alert when I mouseover, are there any other ways of debugging?

Comment: Your update works! 1 problem though, on mouseout it gives me "undefined".
I have the text before: "Eagle.png" (101 KB).
mouseover it, it changes to "Select another image"
mouseout, then it changes to "undefined"

Comment: Hmm interesting, I see that happening too. Let me see if I can fix that, that's silly to me

Comment: @user1994446 Like I thought, something silly. It was the `if` statement in the `onmouseout`. I thought I'd need it but decided not to include it before for whatever reason. It seems to work for me. Check up the updated code again (I just overwrote my UPDATE part)

Comment: :/ now it doesn't change, it flickers quickly back to "Select Image"

Comment: Strange... I tried to select a file while leaving my cursor over the button and it showed the filename, but when I moved my mouse off of the button then it went back to "Select Image" and when trying to hover over it again it doesn't change, remains on "Select Image"

Comment: Thanks so much Ian (see original question, I added the code that worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery it can be written as

```
$(function(){
    var temp = $('#file-button').html();
    if (temp !== "Select Image") {
        $('#file-button').hover(function(){
            $(this).html('Select a different image')
        },function(){
            $(this).html(temp)
        });
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eTwb6/)

Comment: Same thing with this one, I get no errors, but it still does not work.

Comment: yes, and it works fine, could it be something is overwriting what this script is trying to change?

Comment: might be, you can add a console.log statement and check whether this method is getting called

Answer (score -1):

try this one

actually you are binding the event listeners only when the btn's html !== `Select Image`

```
var temp;
$("#file-button").mouseover(function() {
    if ($(this).html() !== "Select Image")
    {
        temp = $(this).html();
        $(this).html("Select a different Image");
    }
}).mouseout(function() {
    if ($(this).html() === "Select a different Image")
        $(this).html(temp);
});
```